# Execute a migration only when it was not executed yet in Doctrine

Tags: php, build, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I've got specific issue, when in building my project, I need to run migration only if it wasn't migrated yet. I know that I can use `$this->skipIf()` inside of migration, but I wanted to have some "external" way to do it, without adding code in every class that I want to run like that.

Is there any way to do it? Flag or something? Tried different things with `:execute` and `:migrate` but no result.

Comment: That should not be necessary. Usually doctrine uses the version table to keep track of which migrations already where executed .

Comment: That's true, but in this specific case, I must execute migrations when db is empty, or NOT execute them if they're marked as executed in migrations table. And the problem is, that if I try to execute older migration, it's executed always, not only if was not executed yet.